# How does flaming sphere work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

In my campaign we have a wizard in our team and we are level 5. Our wizard chose the spell *Flaming Sphere* and we encountered a Goblin horde (30 goblins). He used the spell and moved its 60 feet radius circle area. Is this how it works? And does *Flaming Sphere* trigger friendly fire?

Comment: There are conflicts between what you're asking and what the PHB says for the spell description. Can you cite relevant portions of the spell that support the proposed act and are unclear to you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Flaming Sphere doesn't work like this

> As a **bonus action**, you can move the sphere up to 30 feet. If you ram the sphere into a creature, that creature must make the saving throw against the sphere’s damage, and the sphere **stops moving** this turn.

You have only 1 bonus action each turn, so you can move it up to 30 feet per turn. You can ram it into 1 creature too.

> Any creature that **ends its turn** within 5 feet of the sphere must make a Dexterity saving throw.

You can move it past hundreds of creatures, but they are unaffected, unless you ram it into *one* of them. From the others only those who are stupid enough not to move away and *end* their turn next to it have to save.
If your allies do this, they are burnt too.

Comment: Correct me if ı wrong when I move the orb  it doesnt trigger friendly fire or any damage to other creature

Comment: @MrDewitt while it is moving, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: ah ı get it now

Comment: MrDewitt what do you mean by "friendly fire", that isn't a term used in D&D 5e. Are you talking about attacks of opportunity? Spell effects to not provoke attacks of opportunity.

Comment: No I want to say when a sphere pass or stops near  friendly creature does the creature take damage??